# ActionScript / AIR - File Size Increase with TLF?

Tags: actionscript-3, file, air, size, tlf

i'm developing an AIR application in Flash Professional CS5 and noticed that my .swf file size jumps from around 100kb to 900kb just for using TLF?!  is this normal?  that seems like an awful lot of extra weight for a few more options over regular TextField objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the increased file size was caused by embedding the TLF library as an asset rather than relying on runtime shared libraries.

explination here:  [Working with Text Layout Framework (TLF) text:  Publishing SWF files with TLF text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee-4b0db644124bbdb363d-8000.html#WSb03e830bd6f770ee72b69dc71257a25aa72-8000)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the embedded fonts has way more than characters than you need, you can tell the compiler to include only the character range that you need:

http://blogs.adobe.com/tlf/2008/11/embedded-font-subsetting-using.html

Comment: i only embedded basic latin (95 glyphs).  i'm thinking it might have something to do with the textLayout.swc?